# RSpec - Testing methods that call private methods that should be mocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm using RSpec for testing my classes on Rails.

I'm wondering what is a good way to test methods calling private methods.

For example I have this class:

```
Class Config
  def configuration(overrides)
    @config.merge(overrides)
  end

  private

  def read_config_from_yml
    @config ||= YAML.load()...
  end
end
```

To test the configuration method, we need to somehow mock the read_config_from_yml method. I know it's not good to simply mock the private method `read_config_from_yml` or the instance variable `@config` because that would be messing with the internals of the object.

What I can think of on top of my head:

1. make read_config_from_yml public
2. add setter method for config (to avoid mocking the instance variable)

Are these hacks? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to actually create a copy of the YAML file in the test. You could take a snippet of the file that you're using in your production code, write it to the expected file location and delete it upon test completion.

```
before do
  File.open(file_path_here, 'w+') do |f|
    f << <<-eof
      config:
        setting1: 'string'
        setting2: 0
    eof
  end
end

after do
  File.delete(file_path_here)
end

it 'does the thing' do
  ...
end
```

This would avoid any stubbing and allow you to keep your method private.